# POST request which appears to not have authorization parameters keeps failing

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I'm looking to obtain search results from this URL https://aiwa.ae/keyword/trading 

Site has infinite scrolling, each scroll loads a page with a POST request that is visible under name "GetSearchResults" in network inspector.

Making a request should look like this:

```
import requests
import json
import pprint

url = 'https://aiwa.ae/api/services/app/search/GetSearchResults'
payload = {"query":"trading","searchField":"","sortByField":"relevance","filters":"","pageIndex":3,"pageSize":20,"params":"origin_region=undefined"}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)

pprint.pprint(json.loads(r.content))
```

But result of that is:

```
{'error': {'code': 0,
           'details': None,
           'message': 'An internal error occurred during your request!',
           'validationErrors': None},
 'result': None,
 'success': False,
 'unAuthorizedRequest': False}
```

From what I can see, there should be no authorization needed (even error report implies that). But still, nothing seems to work, I tried passing in headers too but no luck.

Comment: I'd recommend verifying you're allowed to crawl this website first, since, in their terms and conditions they state that `Our Content, as found within our Website and Services, is protected under United Arab Emirates copyrights. The copying, redistribution, use or publication by you of any such Content, is strictly prohibited. Your use of our Website and Services does not grant you any ownership rights to our Content.`

Comment: Network tab in your browser inspect doesn't make it an open API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem relies upon the way you are sending the request. You should change `data=` with `json=` like this:

```
import requests
import pprint

url = 'https://aiwa.ae/api/services/app/search/GetSearchResults'
payload = {"query":"trading","searchField":"","sortByField":"relevance","filters":"","pageIndex":3,"pageSize":20,"params":"origin_region=undefined"}
r = requests.post(url, json=payload)

pprint.pprint(r.json())
```

*(PS: in order to see the request in a JSON format I recommend you to use `r.json()` instead of importing the json library and using `json.loads(r.content)`)*

hope this helps!